# How to produce MathType equations in a MS Word document under Ubuntu?

Tags: libreoffice, latex, microsoft-office

I am asked to type some math formulas that can work in Microsoft Office and MathType equation editor. Can you recommend some ways to produce MathType equations in a MS Word document under Ubuntu?

I only have access to Ubuntu 12.04 near me, there is LibreOffice available under Ubuntu as well, but I am used to type math formulas in LaTex.

I work under Ubuntu, preferably with LaTeX, but LibreOffice or OpenOffice being also acceptable since it is still under Ubuntu.

One way I found is to install MathType under Wine in Ubuntu.
It works, but I cannot copy the equations from MathType into a .doc document opened in LibreOffice Writer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with MathType. If you are searching for a way to integrate LaTex formated formulas in your document using LibreOffice, [TexMaths](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/texmaths-1) is the way to go. See here for more extensive documentation: http://roland65.free.fr/texmaths/

Comment: Thanks!  I actually tried that. The problem is that the formulas created in a .doc file with TexMaths and LibreOffice cannot be edited in MathType and MS Office. Also TeXMaths requires installation of LaTeX, but I am typing equations for someone who doesn't have LaTeX but still want to re-edit my equations with MathType and MS Office.